# How to load a UICollectionViewController on clicking a button in the navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a class, DisplayOptViewController, which is a subclass of UICollectionViewController.
I want to display this CollectionViewController when the user clicks a button in the Navigation Bar on my current page. I am able to load the CollectionView on button Click but the Navigation Bar is not coming. I want the user to be able to see a back button in the navigation Bar and clicking the button should take him back to the current page.
I tried to do this via storyboard as well as programmatically. When I try this via the Storyboard, the ViewController itself is not displayed and when I create the view controller object programmatically, I am not getting the Navigation Bar. Any idea how to to this?

I tried to add this code to my `viewDidLoad` method in `DisplayOptViewController`:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar=[[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:navBar];
```

But the Navigation Bar still didn't come. Kindly help.

*update*

I am loading the UICollectionView here

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[aFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(140, 50)]; 
[aFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
DisplayOptViewController *vc=[[DisplayOptViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:aFlowLayout];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: could you maybe explain better what exactly you want to happen? From what I am understanding, when the user pushes a button on the navigation bar the navigation controller pushes the collectionview onto the screen but hides the navigation bar. Is this what is happening?

Comment: Yes this is what is happening. I am loading the uicollectionView here -[code] UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [aFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(140, 50)];
    [aFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    DisplayOptViewController *vc=[[DisplayOptViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:aFlowLayout];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];[/code]

Comment: why not simply use '[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]' ?

Comment: I tried that as well. But still couldn't see the Navigation Bar on the CollectionViewController page.

Comment: I tried again. Hey It worked now. Thanks @geo

Comment: not for that ^^ using the push method always have to show the nav bar, if you don't tell to hide it. Or you set the controller to modal, then there IS no navBar ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things that i question,

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:navBar];
```

you are adding a navigation bar to a navigation bar.... do this instead

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBar:navBar];
```

second

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you are presenting the controller.... not pushing/poping it....

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

try that in when you do it programmatically

as for the storyboard maybe you don't have the segues set up correctly, or properties not set right or something... but i can't debug it like this

Answer (score 0):

If you have a navigation based project, then you have to initialize the navigation controller in the app delegate itself. Try the code below to make the navigation bar visible,

In  application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method,

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[self viewController]];
[[self window] setRootViewController:navigationController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Now your navigation bar will appear.